# Why multiple joins take forever?

Tags: google-bigquery

I believe I found a bug in Google BigQuery but I'm not sure.
I am hoping someone could offer a workaround.

The table I'm running on a table with only 200K of data.

On my attempts to do a funnel analysis I stumbled upon the following bizarre behaviour:

This takes ~3 seconds:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT Q0._user_id) AS step0
FROM
  (SELECT _user_id FROM [5629499534213120.201501]) AS Q0
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT _user_id, _time FROM [5629499534213120.201501] WHERE _os=='Windows') AS Q1
ON (Q0._user_id=Q1._user_id)
```

This takes **~3 Minutes**:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT Q0._user_id) AS step0
FROM
  (SELECT _user_id FROM [5629499534213120.201501]) AS Q0
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT _user_id, _time FROM [5629499534213120.201501] WHERE _os=='Windows') AS Q1
ON (Q0._user_id=Q1._user_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT _user_id, _time FROM [5629499534213120.201501] WHERE _country=='de') AS Q2
ON (Q0._user_id=Q2._user_id)
```

Meaning adding one more Left Join makes the query unbelievably slow (we're talking about only 200k of data).

Obviously, I have simplified the Select statement so you could focus on the main issue (The real select statement I used is far more complicated)

Does anyone know what's the problem, or a workaround for it?

Comment: What happens when you `LEFT OUTER JOIN [5629499534213120.201501] AS Q2 ON (Q0._user_id=Q2._user_id AND Q2._country=='de') ` ? I think your inner query may be breaking the ability to use indexes

Comment: "ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name."

Comment: Ok, what about moving Q2._country=='de' to the WHERE clause?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you mean to an outside WHERE clause? But that would harm what I'm trying to do with the Outer join. Can you maybe submit an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 5):

I responded to this on the BigQuery issue tracker, but I'm reposting my answer here:

I'm a bigquery engineer and I looked up your query in our logs.
What you're seeing is a join explosion.

You did a 3-way self-join with non-unique keys. The field "_user_id" had a single value that matched 3937 rows on the left, 1388 rows in the first join, and 1388 rows in the second join.

That means you're creating 3937*1388*1488 or 7.5 billion output rows. (you then did a count distinct over them to reduce the output size, but the intermediate values needed to be created first).

It is not surprising that creating 7.5 billion intermediate rows would take a couple of minutes, especially since they were all from a single key, and hence had to be produced by a single worker task.

My guess is that it would be possible to restructure your query to avoid the join explosion.

Comment: Hi Jordan,
Thank you very much for you answer :). 
Hope you don't mind to continue this on the issue tracker. Maybe (please?) you can help me reconstruct the query, I'll then report the modified query here for people to reference.

Comment: Here's the link for anyone who wants to follow: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=213

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with BigQuery specifically, but I suspect the inner queries (`SELECT _user_id, _time FROM [...`) are retrieving the entire table.

What about rewording the query as follows:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT Q0._user_id) AS step0
FROM
  [5629499534213120.201501] AS Q0
LEFT OUTER JOIN [5629499534213120.201501] AS Q1
  ON (Q0._user_id=Q1._user_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN [5629499534213120.201501] AS Q2
  ON (Q0._user_id=Q2._user_id)
WHERE Q1._os=='Windows'
  AND Q2._country=='de'
```

As far as I can tell, the result should be the same; wording it like this should hopefully allow the database to use indexes (if the database is properly normalized).

Comment: The result would not be the same with a complicated select statement, remember the purpose is to create a funnel. (step0, step1, step2) different steps, different conditions.

Comment: I believe it is the funnel that is causing the "join explosion"; that the individual selects are stopping the database select from being smart