# Limits of Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What is the limit on Google BigQuery? I'm trying to run an SQL statement on about 6 GB of data but it seems to be taking a long time (more than an hour), and then when I came back to check on it after half a day I find the error "request timed out. please try again".

I'm assuming 6 GB of data isn't too much compared to what other people might have but it's surprising to me that I'm timing out like that. If it helps, my SQL query is a bit complex and essentially calculates a rolling window unique count  - which I believe generally takes a long time. I also checked to add to a destination table and to "allow large results".

Also, I'm running the query in the Google BigQuery query editor itself (where it says Compose Query).

EDIT: (below is the actual query I'm using)

```
SELECT t1.time, t1.x, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.x)
FROM `data` AS t1
JOIN `data` AS t2 ON t2.time 
BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(t1.time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND t1.time
GROUP BY t1.time, t1.x
```

Here is some sample data:

```
                X
05:20:19        4   <- 2 (4 and 5 are unique)
05:20:19        5   <- 2 (4 and 5 are unique) * same time as before
05:37:18        7   <- 3 (4, 5 and 7 are unique)
05:45:14        4   <- 3 (4, 5, and 7)
05:56:04        4   <- 3 (4, 5, and 7)
06:18:48        6   <- 4 (now 4, 5, 6, and 7)
06:48:34        3   <- 3 (only checks past hour, so now 3, 4, 6)
07:52:48        1   <- 1 (only time in past hour, so only 1)
```

I have about 6GB of that data

Thanks!

Comment: Help us - would you post your query, and some details about your data? I'm sure the community could work out a working query on public data that accomplishes your goals.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Just edited my post to include more details

Comment: Cool - now if the question is "how to do a rolling window unique count" - check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866033/132438

Comment: Thanks! My question is more so whether running an SQL query like mine on about 6GB of data should be taking hours and hours to run or am I just not running it correctly

Comment: @dooer . . . You are essentially cross joining a table with itself.  This can create a ridiculously large intermediate set of rows.  So, yes, it is possible that even BigQuery will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The weak place in your query I see is executing TIMESTAMP_SUB() function within JOIN ON
Instead, I would try to pre-calculate it before JOIN'ing as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t1.time, t1.x, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.x)
FROM (
  SELECT time, x, 
    TIMESTAMP_SUB(time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) time_sub_hour 
  FROM `data`
) AS t1
JOIN `data` AS t2 
ON t2.time BETWEEN time_sub_hour AND t1.time
GROUP BY t1.time, t1.x
```

Meantime, as others mentioned  - you essentially cross joining quite big table with itself thus very high chance for failure

Answer (score 0):

As established in the comments:

- If your question is "how to do a rolling window unique count" - check the  answer to that at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866033/132438.
- If the question is "can I kill any database with 6GB of data", the answer is "yes":

For example, let's say you have 5 million rows of data. That's not too much. But then you do a CROSS JOIN with no filters and you want those rows back.

5 million rows * 5 million rows = 25 trillion rows.

You certainly don't want 25 trillion rows, and if you want them - that will certainly take a lot of time. So please avoid exploding joins.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28181650/132438